# VB 2008 Displaying data in ListBox then Transfer the data to another ListBox

Tags: vb.net

In VB 2008 I created 2 list box. The first list box is to load all the data in my database in a specific row, the other list box is when I double click on the data/item on the first list box the specific data/item need to be transfer to the second list box.

I manage to transfer the data, but the output it gave was wrong. Instead of the actual name of the given data/item the output it gave was `System.Data.DataRowView`.  I tried using `.ToString()` but nothing happens. I used the drag and drop method for the data adapter connection and the database I'm using is MySQL. I use the "Use data bound items" on list box 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this,

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
    ' checks if the item is empty
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.Length <> 0 Then
        ' adds on listbox 2
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

See this,

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, thank you it work you sir help a lot, thank you thank you. I hope I can return the favor someday.

Answer (score 0):

with simple code you can use this

> ```
> Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
>     ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
> End Sub
> ```